# Wifi-direct(P2P) with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, wifi-direct, arduino-uno

Recently I just started learning Arduino and now I'm starting a learning project on which I'd connect more than 2 Arduino Uno powered devices via WiFi-direct(no access point, rather P2P group) and make serial communication over those devices.

After searching for a while I wasn't able to find any suggestion for WiFi-direct(P2P) implementation with Arduino. Any guideline or help content would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: follow this link: https://github.com/asadziach/WiFi101 This library implements a network driver for devices based on the ATMEL WINC1500 wifi module. For more information about this library please visit us at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101

Answer (score 1):

wifi-direct can only make connections to the access point.
A device can only connect to one access point at time.
Anyway you can have an arduino to provide wifi-direct and then use that arduino to command other microcontrollers trough SoftwareSerial library and bluetooth.

Comment: this is not accurate. WiFi Direct is between 2 devices, not involving an access point. Also WiFi direct can commonly be used in parallell with using an access point. So it is perfectly possible for Device A and Device B to build a WiFi Direct group. Device A could simultaneously connect to an access point for internet connection etc.